# After Updating to androidx : 'Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.' Why is the app crashing?

Tags: java, android, layout, navigationview

I'm trying to implement a basic Navigation Drawer in my Android application. It is supposed to appear on the activity right after the User logs in. However, my app crashes as soon as Login is successful.

I tried a few methods which involved checking the location of my drawable images, changing the dependencies and editing the styles. Nothing seems to work.

Stacktrace :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sehat20, PID: 6176
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sehat20/com.example.sehat20.PatientAfterLogin}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:651)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.sehat20.PatientAfterLogin.onCreate(PatientAfterLogin.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler OurAim in class com.example.sehat20.PatientAfterLogin
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:254)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:482)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:530)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:206)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:128)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:264)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:189)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104)
            ... 28 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: OurAim [interface android.view.MenuItem]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:250)
            ... 35 more
```

This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PatientAfterLogin"
    android:background="@color/brandColour"
    android:id="@+id/dl">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/logo">

            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="28dp"
                android:text="Welcome to Sehat!"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:layout_marginTop="230dp">

            </TextView>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is build.gradle :

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sehat20"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

}
```

These is styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/CustomToolBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomToolBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="titleTextColor">@color/textColor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This is the navigation menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_our_aim"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/about_us"
        android:onClick="OurAim">
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_general_info"
        android:title="Personal Information"
        android:icon="@drawable/resume"
        android:onClick="Info">
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_results"
        android:title="Test Results"
        android:icon="@drawable/medical_result"
        android:onClick="Results">
    </item>


    <item android:id="@+id/nav_reminder"
        android:title="Check-up Reminders"
        android:icon="@drawable/calendar"
        android:onClick="Reminders">
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:title="Log Out"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:onClick="LogOut">

    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace

Comment: Remove `customtoolbar` from styles and then try maybe it will work

Comment: @zinonX I tried, however, I am getting the same issue

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I have edited the details in my question

Comment: @HARSHADABELGI please remove `<scrollView` and all other tags use `<include` at place of them

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: **Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler OurAim in class com.example.sehat20.PatientAfterLogin**
>           at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.(SupportMenuInflater.java:254)

In the `PatientAfterLogin` class you have to add this method to handle the click on the menu item:

```
  public boolean OurAim(MenuItem item) {
    // actions
    return ....;
  }
```